# How can I be notified when all requests have been processed after a stop?

Tags: playframework

I have a service I need to stop at the shutdown of my Play application, but I need to be sure that all requests have been processed.
I've overriden the 'onStop' method in Global.scala to be notified, but as requests are handled asynchronously, can I be sure that all requests have all processed when the onStop method is called?

Maybe it's possible to use the underlying Netty API to check that all responses have been sent?

Thanks

Edit :

I made a few tests with gatling, and the stop notify is done before the processing of the last requests

```
[info] application - Response 19528
[info] application - All stoped
[info] play - Shutdown application default Akka system.
[info] application - Start Request 19529
[info] application - Response 19529
[info] application - Start Request 19530
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more about the service? How are you starting and stopping it? How is it fed requests?

Comment: it's a flume client that needs to be flushed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write a play plugin with a high priority (low number, e.g 100) and override the onStop method.